# Prove that for $d, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, if for some nonzero integer $a$ we have $ad\mid an$, then $d\mid n$.

Tags: proof-writing

> Prove that for $d,n\in \mathbb{Z}$, if for some nonzero integer $a$ we have $ad\mid an$, then $d\mid n$. Conversely, if $d\mid n$, then $ad\mid an$ for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$.

For the first part, I got:
If $ad\mid an$, then $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ad⋅k=an \Longrightarrow d\cdot k=n\Longrightarrow d\mid n $

However for the second part,I'm not sure how to go about this except for something that seems rather obvious:

$$d⋅k=n \Rightarrow ad⋅k=an \,\, \forall a \in \mathbb{Z} $$

Also, i'm not sure if the rightarrow i'm using actually is being used correctly. I mean is it being used appropriately in this context. Can the right arrow be taken to mean "therefore"? Thanks.

Comment: $d\,|\,n\implies n=md\implies an=amd$.  that's really what you wrote, of course...so yes.  Your argument is valid.

Comment: Ahh, so I did it the wrong way around.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure.  It's always a good idea to clearly state assumptions and conclusions.  I started with the clear statement $d\,|\,n$, I ended by writing $an$ as an explicit multiple of $ad$ from which I instantly can conclude that $ad\,|\,an$.

Comment: ok, thanks @lulu